# How to pass function in class template without use of auto?

Tags: c++11, templates

I have following function:

```
bool comp(Arm l, Arm r) {
    return l.len < r.len;
}
```

Please, Assume `Arm` is appropriately declared struct.

I have following class:

```
template<typename T, typename F>
class Myclass {
public:
    Arm v[10];
    bool Myfunc(int i) {
        int l = i, r = i + 1;
        return F(v[l], v[s]);
    }
};
```

When creating object:

```
Myclass<Arm, decltype(comp)> obj;
```

I'm getting `error: expression list treated as compound expression in functional cast [-fpermissive]`

I have tried passing address, I have tried creating function pointer and passing that. I wish to get it worked for C++ 11, Using C++17 I got it worked using:

```
template<typename T, auto F>
class Myclass {
...
```

And creating object by:

```
Myclass<Arm, comp> obj;
```

And this was working fine.

Example in C++ 11 giving error:

```
struct Arm {
    int len;
};

template<typename T, typename F>
class Myclass {
public:
    Arm v[10];
    bool Myfunc(int i) {
        int l = i, r = i + 1;
        return F(v[l], v[r]);
    }
};

bool comp(Arm l, Arm r) {
  return l.len < r.len;
}

int main() {
    Myclass<Arm, decltype(comp)> obj;
    obj.Myfunc(2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It looks clear now. I made an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prior to C++17 (which can use `auto` for the template parameter type), it's usually simplest to create a functor, like a lambda or a `struct` with an `operator()` overload:

```cpp
struct comp {
    bool operator()(Arm l, Arm r) const { return l.len < r.len; }
};
```

With that, you need to instantiate the functor when needing it (or store an instance in your class):

```cpp
template<typename T, typename F>
class Myclass {
public:
    // ...
    bool Myfunc(int i) {
        int l = i, r = i + 1;
        return F{}(v[l], v[r]);
//              ^^
//     instantiate the functor
    }
};
```

And since `comp` is now a type, you can instantiate your `Myclass` like so:

```cpp
Myclass<Arm, comp> obj;
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Psae4KfGc)

---

Without a functor, you could specify the function signature in the template parameter list to make `F` a function pointer:

```cpp
struct Arm {
    int len;
};

template <typename T, bool(*F)(T, T)>
//                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
//            the function signature it accepts
class Myclass {
public:
    Arm v[10];
    bool Myfunc(int i) {
        int l = i, r = i + 1;
        return F(v[l], v[r]); // no instantiation needed
    }
};

bool comp(Arm l, Arm r) { return l.len < r.len; }

int main() {
    Myclass<Arm, comp> obj;
    obj.Myfunc(2);
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/jvTEo8z3b)

Comment: Thanks, This works for my use case. But, Is there anyway to do it without functor? I assume there has to be some way.

Comment: @A.J.Sinha You're welcome! I added a non-functor alternative.